# Correct way to retrieve all addresses with their relevant tokenIds

Tags: solidity, remix, tokens, nft, smart-contract-wallets

I've got a NFT collection with a maxSupply of 1000.
All the NFTs have been minted where totalSupply == maxSupply.

What is the best way to retrieve all 1000 addresses along with their relevant tokenIds?

I've tried the below, but the results is not working as expected. Where am I going wrong?

```
 mapping(uint256 => address) private getMintedAddress;

 function getAllAddresses() public view onlyOwner returns (uint256[] memory) {
    uint256 totalMinted = totalSupply();
    uint256[] memory tokenIds = new uint256[](totalMinted);
    for (uint256 i = 1; i < totalMinted; i++) {
        tokenIds[i] = getMintedAddress[i];
    }
    return tokenIds;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

They way you should use your mapping is the other way around.

So you should use:

```
mapping(uint256 => address) private getMintedAddress;
```

As this way you can simply retrieve your addresses like this:

```
uint256 totalMinted = totalSupply();
uint256[] memory tokenIds = new uint256[](totalMinted);

for (uint256 i = 0; i < totalMinted; i++) {
    tokenIds[i] = getMintedAddress[i];
}
```

Here you will get this error: TypeError: Type address is not implicitly convertible to expected type uint256. tokenIds[i] = getMintedAddress[i];

And that is logical because you are saving the address as a uint now. So to just retrieve all balances in tokenId order you need to have this:

```
uint256 totalMinted = totalSupply();
address[] memory tokenAddresses = new address[](totalMinted);

for (uint256 i = 0; i < totalMinted; i++) {
    tokenAddresses[i] = getMintedAddress[i];
}
```

Depending how you increment the tokenIds in your minting function, it could be that you need to change `getMintedAddress[i] to getMintedAddress[i + 1]`

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. 
I'm getting this error:

TypeError: Type address is not implicitly convertible to expected type uint256.
  tokenIds[i] = getMintedAddress[i];

Comment: Hi, i added the problem to the solution given above. I haven't had time to double check but it should work. The error is saying that you save your addresses now as a uint ans they or not convertible like that. So you should ofcourse save those addresses as an address and not a uint :)

Comment: Thank you for your response.
This is what I get when I call the getAllAddress() function:
0:
address[]: 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000

Is there a reason why it isn't returning an address, even though I've minted one NFT?

Comment: well, you got to add the address to the mapping in order for the mapping to hold any values.

Comment: @Zercon A problem is that arrays are zero based and the `i` starts at one. It could be fixed with `tokenAddresses[i - 1] = getMintedAddress[i];`

Comment: @Ismael thanks, i updated the solution.